# How to assign specific customized node color per category to visualize using networkx?

Tags: python, colors, networkx

I have a pandas dataset that have a column for the group that it is assigned to. But I want to customize the color of the node. For example, for group 0 the nodes are red, for group 1 it is blue. Here's what I've tried based on my research, but for some reason it does not really follow the grouping (there should only be 2 colors based on the groups) and I can't edit the colors.

This is my dataset saved in sample.csv file

```
ID|Parent|Group|
1 |   5  |  0  |
2 |   5  |  0  |
3 |   4  |  1  |
4 |   5  |  1  |
5 |   3  |  0  |

sample= pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding='cp1252')
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(sample, 'ID', 'Parent', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

carac=sample.set_index('ID')
carac=sample.reindex(G.nodes())
carac['Group']=pd.Categorical(carac['Group'])
carac['Group'].cat.codes

plt.figure(2,figsize=(5,5)) 
nx.draw(G, node_color=carac['Group'].cat.codes, cmap=plt.cm.Set1, node_size=150)
```

## Result

[image]

## Update: I've also tried this, but it also didn't follow the color grouping

```
# Build your graph
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(sample, 'ID', 'Parent', ['Group'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
G.nodes()

colors = []

for node in G:
    if node in (sample["Group"] == 0):
        colors.append("red")
    elif node in (sample["Group"]== 1): 
        colors.append("blue")
nx.draw(G, with_labels=False, node_size=150, node_color=colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[node_color](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx) is used not for node groups, but for each node itself. You should add to `colors` the color of every node in your graph:

> `node_color (color string, or array of floats, (default=’#1f78b4’)) – Node color. Can be a single color format string, or a sequence of colors with the same length as nodelist. If numeric values are specified they will be mapped to colors using the cmap and vmin,vmax parameters. See matplotlib.scatter for more details.`

```
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(20, 50, directed=True)

# Not for groups, but for each node
colors = ['red' if n > 10 else 'blue' for n in G.nodes]

nx.draw(G, with_labels=False, node_size=150, node_color=colors)
```

[image]

Also be careful for your `colors` array length be equal to the length of `G.nodes`! If they will be different, `node_color` **will be ignored!**

```
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(20, 50, directed=True)

# Because of .pop(), the length of colors is different
colors = ['red' if n > 10 else 'blue' for n in G.nodes].pop()

nx.draw(G, with_labels=False, node_size=150, node_color=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, how can I check if the value of the sample['Group'] is 0 or 1? I've tried colors = ['red' if sample['Group'] > 0 else 'blue' for sample['Group'] in G.nodes] but it showed me an error The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Comment: `for sample['Group'] in G.nodes` is definetly a wrong code. You should use something like: `colors = ['red' if sample['Group'][G.nodes[n]['ID']] > 0 else 'blue' for n in G.nodes]`

Comment: for-statements uses variable for index. If you use `sample['Group']`, you will get an error. `n in G.nodes` will iterate for nodes. `G.nodes[n]['ID']` will get an ID for each node. Then you should extract group according to this ID. I am not sure `sample['Group'][G.nodes[n]['ID']]` will work, but the correct code will be very similar for this.

Comment: I've tried this but for some reason it showed a Keyerror: 'ID'

Comment: Try this: `colors=['red' if int(sample.loc[df['ID'] == n]['Group']) ==0 else 'blue' for n in G.nodes]`

Comment: This works! Thanks! Can you explain what this part does `int(sample.loc[sample['ID'] == n]['Group'])`? It's oddly different from the other sources that I found

Comment: is it really necessary to define it as integer? or can string value also work?

Comment: I will be appreciated to you if you will accept the answer :) `sample.loc` filters rows. `sample['ID'] == n` get a currect node (by its ID). So `sample.loc[sample['ID'] == n]` gets the one line. `sample.loc[sample['ID'] == n]['Group']` gets a group in that line. Yes, `int()` is needed because there is `Grouped` object (like `Series` in Pandas).

Comment: Thanks! Ive encountered another problem when I applied this to a larger dataset. It threw me an error of `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>` for some reason

Comment: It means that you probably have several nodes with one ID. `sample.loc[sample['ID'] == n]` in this case will return several elements that can't be converted to `int`

Comment: Oh okay! Is there a way to maybe bypass this?

Comment: Check the uniqueness of your IDs or get only the first element of `Grouped`, if it has several.

Comment: Okay! Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi sorry to have to ask you this, but I removed all the duplicate IDs that I have but it still returned me the error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: Well, it is strange, with unique IDs it should work. Try to get the first element of series then.

Comment: What do you mean by getting the first element of the series?

Comment: Is it required for the ID to be in consecutive order? Cause my dataset is randomized